# Cómo asignar valores por defecto en los parámetros de la declaración de una función en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
  function generarTabla({
    dataSource,
    fieldPanel = {
        visible: true,
        showColumnFields: false,
        showRowFields: true,
        showDataFields: false,
        showFilterFields: false
    },
}){
 console.log({ fieldPanel })
}
```

Cuando llamo la función y no paso nada en *fieldPanel* toma los valores establecidos por defecto. Pero si paso en el objeto una sola propiedad, elimina el resto de los valores y solo toma el que pasé.
Ejemplo:

```
 generarTabla({
    'dataSource',
    fieldPanel: {
        showColumnFields: true,
    }
})
```

En la consola me aparece lo siguiente:

> {
> "fieldPanel": {
> "showColumnFields": true
> }
> }

Cómo puedo hacer para que tome el resto de las propiedades de la declaración por defecto.
Resultado esperado:

```
    {
    "visible": true,
    "showColumnFields": true,
    "showRowFields": true,
    "showDataFields": false,
    "showFilterFields": false
}
```

Agradezco cualquier orientación o sugerencia sobre cómo implementar esto de manera efectiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el operador [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function generarTabla(fieldPanelOptions){
 
 //Aqui pones los valores Default
 const fieldPanelDefault = {
      visible: true,
      showColumnFields: false,
      showRowFields: true,
      showDataFields: false,
      showFilterFields: false
   };
   
   //unes los valores default con los que ingresan como argumentos
   fieldPanelOptions = {...fieldPanelDefault,...fieldPanelOptions}; 
   console.log(fieldPanelOptions);
}

generarTabla();
generarTabla({showColumnFields: true});
```